# Sobol sequence in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Does anyone know how to code (or have a code) for generating sobol sequences in matlab?

The initial chosen direction numbers is not a concern.

Thanks.

Comment: If you do not have access to the statistics toolbox, you might want to consider translating the Fortran 77 implementation in the corresponding Numerical Recipes book to Matlab. The book is accessible online [here](http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html), section 7.7, pages 299-305.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the stats toolbox function [sobolset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/sobolset.html) unless you're planning on programming your own from scratch?

Otherwise it looks like these file exchange entries can do it without the stats toolbox:

1. [Global sensitivity analysis toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40759-global-sensitivity-analysis-toolbox)
2. [Bridge Sampling](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37622-bridge-sampling)

And [also this one](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11631-interface-to-sobol-gsl-implementation) if you are running Linux. I recommend you start with the file exchange options as they are free, don't require the toolbox and don't require you to start from scratch. Unless you have the toolbox, in which case it's quite well documented so use that.

Comment: Thanks, but I am planning on programming my own sequence from scratch.

Comment: @user2329754 Then you should reflect that in your question and also show an attempt at starting yourself. Either way, you can look at the code in the file exchange entries linked in my answer to see how others have done it.